# MKPointAnnotation was deallocated while key value observers

Tags: ios, mkmapview, mkannotation

I am getting below error, while adding annotation

An instance 0x21fcadd0 of class `MKPointAnnotation` was deallocated while key value observers were still registered with it. Observation info was leaked, and may even become mistakenly attached to some other object. Set a breakpoint on `NSKVODeallocateBreak` to stop here in the debugger.

Here's the current observation info:

(
   Context: 0x0, Property: 0xb74f170>
    )

my code is below putting pin more than 100.

```
 if ([arrListing count] != 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < [arrListing count]; i++) {


            Listing *obj = [arrListing objectAtIndex:i];
            NSLog(@"Title %@  long:%@  Lat:%@",obj.Title,obj.log,obj.lat);

            CLLocationCoordinate2D annotationCoord;

            annotationCoord.latitude = [obj.lat floatValue];
            annotationCoord.longitude = [obj.log floatValue];

                // do something
                MKPointAnnotation *annotationPoint = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];
                annotationPoint.coordinate = annotationCoord;
                annotationPoint.title = obj.Title;
                //  annotationPoint.subtitle = obj.log;
                [mapView addAnnotation:annotationPoint];



        }
    }    
}
```

thank in advanced

Comment: Can you add some code so we can get an idea of what you are trying to do?

Comment: This all looks fine. Can you show us where you're breaking this down and where the annotation would be deallocated?

Comment: Are all the longitudes between -180 and +180 and are all the latitudes between -90 and +90?

Comment: Al the longitudes between -180 and +180 and are all the latitudes between -90 and +90 are not bettween it.

Comment: So the latitudes are not all in the range -90 to +90?  Invalid coordinates can cause that error.  For example, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5872547/warning-in-custom-map-annotations-iphone.

Answer (score 0):

This means that you may have mistaken latitude and longitude.

Latitude should be between -90 and 90, and longitude should be between -180 and 180.