# Instance of class was deallocated while key value observers were still registered with it

Tags: ios, mapkit, mkannotation

I am adding annotations and there are supposed to be 5 annotation pins on my map but only 2 appear and this error is shown:

> An instance 0x9d8e720 of class Annotation was deallocated while key
>   value observers were still registered with it. Observation info was
>   leaked, and may even become mistakenly attached to some other object.
>   Set a breakpoint on NSKVODeallocateBreak to stop h

```
//NUH COORDINATES
#define NUH_latitude 1.293700; 
#define NUH_longitude 103.783353;

//span
#define the_span 0.002f;

//NHGP COORDINATES!
#define NHGP_latitude 1.295938;
#define NHGP_longitude 103.782857;

//NUHER COORDINATES
#define NUHER_latitude 1.294968;
#define NUHER_longitude 103.783716;

//NUCIS COORDINATES
#define NUCIS_latitude 1.293149;
#define NUCIS_longitude 103.783464;

//Viva-UCCC COORDINATES!
#define VivaUCCC_latitude 1.294099;
#define VivaUCCC_longitude 103.783233;

//span
MKCoordinateSpan span;
span.latitudeDelta = the_span;
span.longitudeDelta = the_span;
MKCoordinateRegion myRegion;

//center
CLLocationCoordinate2D center;
center.latitude = NUH_latitude;
center.longitude = NUH_longitude;
myRegion.center =center;
myRegion.span = span;
[mapview setRegion:myRegion animated:YES];

//annotation
NSMutableArray * locations = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
CLLocationCoordinate2D location;
Annotation * myAnn;

//NUH location
myAnn = [[Annotation alloc] init];
location.latitude = NUH_longitude;
location.longitude = NUH_longitude;
myAnn.coordinate = location;
myAnn.title = @"NUH";
[locations addObject:myAnn];

//NHGP location
myAnn = [[Annotation alloc] init];
location.latitude = NHGP_latitude;
location.longitude = NHGP_longitude;
myAnn.coordinate = location;
myAnn.title = @"National Healthcare Group Polyclinic ";
[locations addObject:myAnn];

//NUHER location
myAnn = [[Annotation alloc] init];
location.latitude = NUHER_longitude;
location.longitude = NUHER_longitude;
myAnn.coordinate = location;
myAnn.title = @"National University Hospital Emergency Room";
[locations addObject:myAnn];

//NUCIS location
myAnn = [[Annotation alloc] init];
location.latitude = NUCIS_longitude;
location.longitude = NUCIS_longitude;
myAnn.coordinate = location;
myAnn.title = @"National University Cancer Institute Singapore";
[locations addObject:myAnn];

//Viva-UCCC location
myAnn = [[Annotation alloc] init];
location.latitude = VivaUCCC_latitude;
location.longitude = VivaUCCC_longitude;
myAnn.coordinate = location;
myAnn.title = @"Viva-University Children's Cancer Centre";
[locations addObject:myAnn];

[self.mapview addAnnotations:locations];
```

Comment: This error commonly happens when the coordinates are invalid.  Make sure latitude is from -90 to +90 and longitude is from -180 to +180.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5872547/warning-in-custom-map-annotations-iphone?lq=1.

Comment: i got the coordinates from google map, latitude is from -90 to +90 and longitude is from -180 to +180 for all my annotation pins. but  still cannot get all my pins working. @AnnaKarenina

Comment: Show the code where the annotations are added (Edit your question and add the code) and how the coordinate property is set.

Comment: done editing, sorry im new here hence idk why so many spacing. @AnnaKarenina

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've specified longitudes for the latitudes for NUH, NUHER, and NUCIS. They won't show up where you intended (which is why you only see 2), and I think the error is because those values are not valid for latitudes.

```
//NUH location
location.latitude = NUH_longitude; // <-- should be NUH_latitude
... 
//NUHER location
location.latitude = NUHER_longitude; // <-- should be NUHER_latitude
... 
//NUCIS location
location.latitude = NUCIS_longitude; // <-- should be NUCIS_latitude
```

Answer (score 0):

It could be because you keep reallocting the same myAnn variable. You should try creating multiple `Annotation`s, call them myAnn1, myAnn2 if you have to.

Later on if you have more than 3 of these things you should consider making a collection and looping through it rather than creating them one-by-one