# MKMapAnnotationManager not removing itself as observer for MKAnnotation

Tags: macos, cocoa, mapkit, key-value-observing, kvc

I'm still working on this, but figured it was worth asking about:

I have a class that conforms to the `MKAnnotation` protocol called `AMAnnotation`. This class also implements `setCoordinate:`

```
- (void)setCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)newCoordinate
{
    NSLog(@"%@ %@", self, NSStringFromSelector(_cmd));
    _coordinate = newCoordinate;
}
```

I can successfully add the annotation to a map and I can call `setCoordinate:` and the pin will move on the map. But there's a problem. *Sometimes*, when the map gets deallocated, the program will pause on `NSKVODeallocateBreak` with the following message:

```
An instance 0x608000a626c0 of class AMAnnotation was deallocated while key value observers were still registered with it. Observation info was leaked, and may even become mistakenly attached to some other object. Set a breakpoint on NSKVODeallocateBreak to stop here in the debugger. Here's the current observation info:
<NSKeyValueObservationInfo 0x60800045ca70> (
<NSKeyValueObservance 0x600000ac0460: Observer: 0x60800038ead0, Key path: coordinate, Options: <New: NO, Old: YES, Prior: YES> Context: 0x0, Property: 0x60000045fad0>
<NSKeyValueObservance 0x600000ac0460: Observer: 0x60800038ead0, Key path: coordinate, Options: <New: NO, Old: YES, Prior: YES> Context: 0x0, Property: 0x60000045fad0>
<NSKeyValueObservance 0x600000ac0460: Observer: 0x60800038ead0, Key path: coordinate, Options: <New: NO, Old: YES, Prior: YES> Context: 0x0, Property: 0x60000045fad0>
<NSKeyValueObservance 0x600000ac0460: Observer: 0x60800038ead0, Key path: coordinate, Options: <New: NO, Old: YES, Prior: YES> Context: 0x0, Property: 0x60000045fad0>
<NSKeyValueObservance 0x600000ac0460: Observer: 0x60800038ead0, Key path: coordinate, Options: <New: NO, Old: YES, Prior: YES> Context: 0x0, Property: 0x60000045fad0>
<NSKeyValueObservance 0x600000ac0460: Observer: 0x60800038ead0, Key path: coordinate, Options: <New: NO, Old: YES, Prior: YES> Context: 0x0, Property: 0x60000045fad0>
<NSKeyValueObservance 0x600000ac0460: Observer: 0x60800038ead0, Key path: coordinate, Options: <New: NO, Old: YES, Prior: YES> Context: 0x0, Property: 0x60000045fad0>
<NSKeyValueObservance 0x600000ac0460: Observer: 0x60800038ead0, Key path: coordinate, Options: <New: NO, Old: YES, Prior: YES> Context: 0x0, Property: 0x60000045fad0>
)
```

I don't add any observers myself, so I overrode the KVO methods on my `AMAnnotation` class. It turns out that each time I call `setCoordinate:` after the annotation has been added to the map, I see the following:

```
<AMAnnotation: 0x60800086eac0> _original_setCoordinate:
<AMAnnotation: 0x60800086eac0> addObserver:forKeyPath:options:context: <MKMapAnnotationManager: 0x60800038d270> coordinate
```

Now, I don't know what `_original_setCoordinate:` is, Google wasn't helpful. And it looks like the `MKMapAnnotationManager` re-adds itself as an observer but isn't removing itself.

*Sometimes* when the map is deallocated, I see that it removes itself multiple times. But other times not at all, which is when the warnings show up.

```
<AMAnnotation: 0x60800086eac0> removeObserver:forKeyPath: <MKMapAnnotationManager: 0x60800038d270> coordinate
<AMAnnotation: 0x60800086eac0> removeObserver:forKeyPath: <MKMapAnnotationManager: 0x60800038d270> coordinate
<AMAnnotation: 0x60800086eac0> removeObserver:forKeyPath: <MKMapAnnotationManager: 0x60800038d270> coordinate
<AMAnnotation: 0x60800086eac0> removeObserver:forKeyPath: <MKMapAnnotationManager: 0x60800038d270> coordinate
<AMAnnotation: 0x60800086eac0> dealloc
```

Anyone have an explanation for this? Thanks.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5872547/warning-in-custom-map-annotations-iphone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hate when this happens, but it looks like I solved it.  It seems that the `MKMapAnnotationManager` gets confused when updating an annotation with an invalid coordinate. (At least, that's what I've observed while debugging this problem.) If I check for invalid coordinates *before* updating the annotation and remove the annotation if it is invalid and re-add when valid, it seems to work and properly calls the add/remove observer methods as needed.

You can check for a valid coordinate with `CLLocationCoordinate2DIsValid()`.  Also the constant `kCLLocationCoordinate2DInvalid` might come in handy.